# Kubernetes exposed pod connection refused - one time works, sometime not

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes instalation with master and 1 node.

It is configured and everything is working very good.

```
$ kubectl get pods

NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE 
mantis-gfs    1/1       Running   1          22h 
mongodb-gfs   1/1       Running   0          14h
```

I exposed the pod mongodb-gfs:

```
$ kubectl expose pod mongodb-gfs --port=27017 --external-ip=10.9.8.100 --name=mongodb --labels="env=development"
```

The extrnal IP 10.9.8.100 is the IP of the kubernetes master node

The service was created successfully.

```
$ kubectl get services

NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
glusterfs-cluster   ClusterIP   10.111.96.254   <none>        1/TCP       23d
kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP     29d
mongodb             ClusterIP   10.100.149.90   10.9.8.100    27017/TCP   1m
```

Now i am able to access the mongo using:

```
mongo 10.9.8.100:27017
```

And here is the problem. It works some time, but some time not.
I connect once and i get the shell, i connect second time and get:

```
$ mongo 10.9.8.100:27017

MongoDB shell version v3.4.17
connecting to: mongodb://10.9.8.100:27017/test
2018-11-01T09:27:23.524+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 10.9.8.100:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-11-01T09:27:23.524+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 10.9.8.100:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Then i try again and it works, try again it works, try again it not works...

Any clues what may cause the problem?

Answer (score 10):

I found the problem and the solution. The problem was, the pod definition. For both pods: mongodb-gfs and mantis-gfs i have the same label settings. Then i exposed services with the same label="env=development". In this case the traffic that i expected to go always to one pod was "loadbalanced" to one or other pod (they have the same label) of different types.

Changing the label in the mongodb-gfs pod definition solved the problem with connection issues.

Comment: Same issue for me but I have only one pod, simple httpd service for testing, port is 80, external port is one of the cluster IP address, and I get the same issue, sometimes it connect, sometimes not.
So not sure if this is a POD LABEL Issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and przemas led me in the right direction with the selectors. When different pods have the same selector labels k8s selects the wrong one sometimes. You have to choose unique names for the selectors. Weird that this is not logged anywhere which pod is selected.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: revproxy-svc
spec:
 selector:
   role: app
 type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: loadbalance-svc
spec:
 selector:
   role: app
 type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: loadbalancer-python
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     role: app
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       role: app

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: revproxy
spec:
 replicas: 2
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     role: app
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       role: app
```